# Determine if language $L=\{xyxz\,\,|\,\,x\neq\varepsilon,\,\,x,y,z\in\{0,1\}^{*}\}$ is regular

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-language, regular-expressions

**Question.**

> Determine if the language is regular:
>
> $L=\{xyxz\,\,|\,\,x\neq\varepsilon,\,\,x,y,z\in\{0,1\}^{*}\}$

I think $L$ is non regular, because of the second x.

I'm trying to prove with the Pumping Lemma, but I'm not so sure how to choose the word.

Comment: Think about what words are not in this language. Remember that regularity is closed over complement.

Comment: @rici so use the lemma on $\overline{L}$  ?

Comment: Figure out what the complement is. Ask yourself if it's regular. Remember that regular expressions are about recognition, not parsing. Can you think of *any* string in the complement of L?

Comment: @rici e.g. $01^{n}$ ,$10^{n}$,$\varepsilon$ but I can't recognize what the complementary language is

Comment: Taking the complement is a neat trick here, regarding recognizing it as a language I would try to think about building a string in the language one character at a time. If we start with a $0,$ what can we choose next? (is $0aw$ guaranteed to be in $L$ for some bit $a$ and any string $w$?) What if we start with $1$? After you consider these routes you may find that the complement is more restrictive than you'd originally thought.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. You already observed that
$$
  \varepsilon \cup 01^* \cup 10^* \subseteq L^c
$$
Now use the fact that
$$
  0\{0,1\}^*0\{0,1\}^* \cup 1\{0,1\}^*1\{0,1\}^* \subseteq L
$$
to conclude.